# How to config FeignClient run in docker compose

Tags: openfeign, sbt-docker-compose

In my application, I use the SpingCloud framework to create microservices, including:

- ApiGateway  (http://localhost:6800)
- ExampleService (http://localhost:6801)

In ExampleService, I have 3 controllers:

- Service1Controller: path "api/service1"
- Service2Controller: path "api/service2"
- Service3Controller: path "api/service3"

In ApiGateway, I created 3 FeignClient Interface class and 3 Controller to call to ExampleServices:

```
@FeignClient(value = "service"//Name of course-service application
                    , path = "/api/service1"//Pre-path for course-service
                    , url = "${service.url}" //http://localhost:6801
                    , configuration = FeignConfiguration.class
)
public interface Service1Request {
....
}

------------------
@RestController
@RequestMapping("gateway/service1") //pre-path
public class Service1Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Service1Request service1Request;

    .....
}
```

```
@FeignClient(contextId="service2", value = "service"//Name of course-service application
                    , path = "/api/service2"//Pre-path for course-service
                    , url = "${service.url}" //http://localhost:6801
                    , configuration = FeignConfiguration.class
)
public interface Service2Request {
....
}


------------------
@RestController
@RequestMapping("gateway/service2") //pre-path
public class Service2Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Service2Request service2Request;

    .....
}
```

```
@FeignClient(contextId="service3", value = "service"//Name of course-service application
                    , path = "/api/service3"//Pre-path for course-service
                    , url = "${service.url}" //http://localhost:6801
                    , configuration = FeignConfiguration.class
)
public interface Service3Request {
....
}

------------------
@RestController
@RequestMapping("gateway/service3") //pre-path
public class Service3Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Service3Request service3Request;

    .....
}
```

When I build and run services local, they are working fine.
But when I build in docker (docker compose), ApiGateway only connects to Service1 (api/service1), ApiGateway can not connect to Service2(api/service2), Service3(api/service3).

Please help me to fix the problem. Thanks!